# What is causing my jQuery functions not run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I can't figure out why the jQuery functions will not work with the html here
JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JonaTheApprentice/E89rg/

```
function addItem() {
    $('#list').append('<li><input type="checkbox" /> item</li>');
}

function removeItem() {
    $('#list').children().filter(function () {
        return this.firstChild.checked;
    }).remove();
}
```

Comment: you don't have #list in your html

Comment: You don't have any elements with the id of `list` in your HTML.  Also, you should not use inline event handlers.

Comment: @minitech i don't see how this question was off topic when there were multiple people engaged in solving the issue.

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting." – minitech

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see an element with `id="list"`, that's what `#list` refers to.

I think you mean `#items-listed`. Changing that, and it works

Comment: Should the id go in the button or form?

Comment: i.e. replace `$('#list')` with `$('#items-list')`.

Comment: i feel so naive. I am doing as you suggested http://jsfiddle.net/JonaTheApprentice/E89rg/1/

Comment: Not your fault - jsfiddle requires you to change it to "no wrap - in body" to run functions in the global scope like that. Tought you may want to use jquery dom ready and click events instead of onlicks like that. http://jsfiddle.net/E89rg/2/

Comment: You could also use jQuery's `$().on` binding to add onclick listeners to specific elements. http://jsfiddle.net/E89rg/3/

Comment: Appreciate your time. When you add something to the textbox and hit enter. What is coming up in the list? On my side it just displays item no matter what.

Comment: That's because your hard-coded `<li><input type="checkbox" /> item</li>` as what's appended. I've rewritten your script a bit to use pure jQuery and to clear out the input value after you add an item: http://jsfiddle.net/E89rg/4/

Answer (score 1):

I would get the value from the input `id`. I would also assign a click event for cleaner coding. Here is an example of your fiddle adding an item. Removing an item is just the reversal.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/E89rg/5/

```
$('#Enter').click(function(){
  var Val = $('#item').val();
  $('#items-listed').append('<li><input type="checkbox" />'+Val+'</li>');
});
```